# How to read variable stored in .py file in azure blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am having a hard time importing variables stored in a .py file that is stored in azure blob storage. I am able to download the file and read the contents as a string, but unable to find a way to treat the file as a .py file and import variables from it. My code as is looks like this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service = BlobServiceClient(account_url="<url>", credential="<key>")
client = blobService.get_blob_client(container='<container>', blob='file.py')
file = client.download_blob()
bytes_string = file.readall()
```

If I print bytes_string it gives me something like `b'x = 2'`. Is there a way I can do the equivalent of `import x from file.py` so I can work with the data stored in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think importing straight from your stream variable or a string from readall() is possible, because as far as I know, import is looking for modules in the filesystem project structure. The only way to do this is to save the file and import it. This works (I had to add some extra stuff at the beginning to make sure the module path resolved correctly for me):

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

download_file_path = "download.py"
blob_service = BlobServiceClient(account_url="<url", credential="<key>")
client = blob_service.get_blob_client(container='<container>', blob='file.py')

with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(client.download_blob().readall())

from download import *
print(x)
```